# Permission Denied using Xamarin.Mobile to access contact list xamarin.form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hey Good Day Everyone I am using Xamarin.Mobile but I got error on Permission Denied I already added the READ_CONTACTS in AndroidManifest and also Add permission at runtime. How to solve this?

Method

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MobileUserContact>> GetAllContacts()
    {
        if (_contacts != null) return _contacts;

        var contacts = new List<MobileUserContact>();
        await _book.RequestPermission().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.Result)
            {
                Log.Debug("PERM", "Permission Denied!");
                return;
            }
            foreach (var contact in _book.Where(c => c.Emails.Any())) // Filtering the Contact's that has E-Mail addresses
            {
                var firstOrDefault = contact.Emails.FirstOrDefault();
                if (firstOrDefault != null)
                {
                    contacts.Add(new MobileUserContact()
                    {
                        ContactFirstName = contact.FirstName,
                        ContactLastName = contact.LastName,
                        ContactDisplayName = contact.DisplayName,
                        ContactEmailId = firstOrDefault.Address,
                        ContactNumber = contact.Phones.ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        _contacts = (from c in contacts orderby c.ContactFirstName select c).ToList();
        return _contacts;
    }
```

Comment: Are you testing on Android 6.0?

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis Android API 23 yap android 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'r not asking for user permission to access their contacts.

Take a look in here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin
and I would advise to use this one too: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Contacts